# How to rename columns of a pandas dataframe with not exact match?

Tags: pandas

I have about 100 Excel files which I am reading via pandas and it contains column names that are similar but are not exactly same. How can I change column names via regex in pandas dataframe?

```
regex_keep = {
  'CAR_ID': 'item *code', 
  'CAR_PRICE': 'item *price',
  'CAR_PERIOD': 'car *period'
             }
```

df columns could be item Code, item code, item_code

Answer (score 0):

We can use df.rename with the API `df.rename(index=str, columns={"old_col_name":"new_col_name", "old_col_name":"new_col_name"})`

But I think we can't directly incorporate the regex inside that statement, so we must find the exact column name first using the regex (via `df.columns`), then pass the {old: new} pair to the `rename` method.

For your specific case, what we can do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['item code', 'item_Price', 'car_period'])
replacement = {r"item[_ ]code": "CAR_ID", r"item[_ ]price": "CAR_PRICE", "car[_ ]period": "CAR_PERIOD"}
column_repl_map = {col: col for col in df.columns}
for key in column_repl_map:
    for pattern, repl in replacement.items():
        if re.match(pattern, key.lower()):
            column_repl_map[key] = repl
df = df.rename(index=str, columns=column_repl_map)
print(df.columns)

[OUT]: Index(['CAR_ID', 'CAR_PRICE', 'CAR_PERIOD'], dtype='object')
```